# Does Flash CS4 have an alternative to ASDoc?

Tags: flash, documentation, asdoc

Does anybody know of a tool that will allow me to create ASDoc style documentation with a Flash CS4/AS3 application? From what I hear ASDoc only works with Flex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this for a while, I decided that the best tool out there for automated AS3 documentation in Flash (not Flex) is [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/). I highly recommend it if you want JavaDoc style documentation in your Flash projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASDoc with FlashDevelop to document any AS3 source, whether its for Flex or Flash.  I've just done it myself for the first time.  Download a trial version of Flash Builder 4, which includes ASDoc--of course you could use Flash Builder itself, or even call ASDoc directly from the command line.  FlashDevelop offers a free route with a good user interface.  And for programming AS3, FlashDevelop is an absolutely superb IDE.